# Simple bashscript for checking open port

Tags: linux, bash

I quite this  script in bash:

```
probe='nc -zv localhost 19997'
output=' grep -c 'succeeded' $probe'
if [ $output == '0' ]
then
     echo 'Client online'
else
     echo 'Offline'
fi
```

The purpose of the script is to check via netcat if a client connected via reverse ssh to my server on port 19997 and print a positive message if this was detectet. nc would print

```
 Connection to localhost 19997 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

if it detects the client and I would like to grep only the 'succeeded' as a keyword for the established connection and trigger the if-statement via the exit code of grep.
But when i run this script I get:

```
test.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: You are assigning strings to your variables. You want to use command substitution `probe=$(nc...)`. And quote your expansions: `[ "$output" == '0' ]`.

Comment: You confused a single quote character `'` with backqoute `.

Comment: Paste your shell scripts in at shellcheck.net to catch these sorts of syntax errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can test on the results of the command directly like so:

```
if ( nc -zv localhost 19997 2>&1 >/dev/null ); then
    echo 'Online'
else
    echo 'Offline'
fi
```

the subshell `( ... )` is not necessary but I like using them when testing like this for cleanliness.

For more reading on exit codes and testing see:

- [Exit and Exit Status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)
- [Test Constructs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html)

Comment: I tried to depend the if-statement of the exit-code of grep, but your solution works much better. Many thanks!

Comment: This is a very elegant solution